# Python: Add minutes or seconds to a time only object

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I need to add a given number of minutes or seconds to a Time object that comes without the date portion.

> For Ex:
>
> Time: 13:00:00 + 10 minutes (Should return 13:10:00)
>
> Time: 21:50:00 + 1800 seconds (Should return 22:20:00)

My code:

```
from datetime import timedelta

d = timedelta(minutes=30)
calendar_entry + d  #calendar_entry is a time object HH:MM:SS
```

Error:

```
During handling of the above exception (unsupported operand type(s) 
for +: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.timedelta'), another exception 
occurred:
```

How can I do this in Python 3?

Comment: What should 23:55:00 + 10 minutes result in…? At best that’s ambiguous, that’s why `time` doesn’t support addition. You’ll also get into trouble if you’re crossing DST change boundaries.

Comment: check the answer I've posted using timedelta() (datetime).

Comment: @deceze this is within a day so it cannot exceed 24 hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
from datetime import date, datetime, time, timedelta
dt = datetime.combine(date.today(), time(13, 0)) + timedelta(minutes=10)
print (dt.time())
#13:10:00
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's what you want:

```
import datetime

date = datetime.datetime.strptime('15:57:12', '%H:%M:%S')
print(date.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
date = date+datetime.timedelta(seconds=1800)
print(date.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
date = date+datetime.timedelta(minutes=30)
print(date.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
```

Output:

```
15:57:12
16:27:12
16:57:12
```

Answer (score 1):

This way of manipulation is only possible with datetime objects, but luckily, you can do the conversion from datetime to time, to have it your way. Take a look at add_minutes:

```
import datetime

def add_minutes(tm, minutes1):
    fulldate = datetime.datetime(100, 1, 1, tm.hour, tm.minute, tm.second)
    fulldate = fulldate + datetime.timedelta(minutes=minutes1)
    return fulldate.time()

a = datetime.datetime.now().time()
b = add_minutes(a, 2)
print(a)
print(b)
```